# Include external dependencies when relying on internal module

Tags: maven, jar, module, dependencies

I have two maven modules - A and B. The module A depends on external jar C. Module B depends on module A. How to make module B include same dependencies module A relies on?

The thing is that my A module is a backend, which chooses a database - postgresql in my case. I don't want my front-end (module B) to know anything about it... but if I don't include that postgresql dependency also in module B it won't work.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Module A would be a dependency of module B.

External JAR C would be a dependency of module A.

Extneral JAR C would subsequently be a *transitive dependency* of module B.

---

You would define A to be a `<dependency>` of module B, through the Maven POM of module B.

You would define C to be a `<dependency>` of module A, through the Maven POM of module A.

External JAR C would subsequently become a transitive dependency of module B. You can check that with a command such as `mvn dependency:list` on B.

---

What you're seeing here is most basic dependency management of Maven, which it is really powerful at.

External JAR C could be something like `org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1003-jdbc4`.